# Solving a system of nonlinear equations with dependent variables

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Consider the following system of equations
$$    7 x + 0.9 \tanh(x + y) = 8.94  \\
    5.5 x + 1.8 \tanh ( x+y ) = - 1.66 $$

I have seen different kinds of system of equations including linear and nonlinear ones, but I am doubtful using which technique I shall solve this system. For instance, is it possible to take the whole term $\tanh(x+y)$ as a new variable $z$ and solve the obtained apparently linear system of equations? My own answer to this question is no, as variable $z$ is depending on the variation of $x$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can make the substitution. After solving for $x,z$, you can then find $y$,

Comment: `is it possible to take the whole term tanh(x+y) as a new variable z` Yes, it is. Or directly, eliminate the $\tanh(x+y)$ term between the two equations and solve for $x$, then once $x$ is known solve either equation for $y$.

Comment: I expected to see a different solution, as I thought that the system should  not be a linear one. Thanks for prompt answers though. What if instead of the second equation we had for instance  $2x+3y=-2$?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach (in my opinion) is to double the first equation to get

$$14x+1.8\tanh(x+y)=17.88$$

Subtract the second equation from this to get

$$8.5x=19.54$$

$$x=\frac{977}{425}$$

And $y$ can then be solved for trivially.

Comment: $x$ is not $\frac{977}{85}$, that's well over $10$, and it multiplied by over $8$ is less than $20$

Comment: @RobinAldabanx Oh shoot, my bad, was trying to simplify those fractions in my head and that's what I get.

Answer (score 1):

Mutiply the first equation by $2$ to get:

$$14x+1.8\tanh(x+y)=17.88$$

Then, subtract the second equation from the first, getting:

$$14x-5.5x+1.8\tanh(x+y)-1.8\tanh(x+y)=17.88-(-1.66)$$

Which simplifies to:

$$8.5x=19.54$$

So now $x$ can be shown to equal $\frac{1954}{850}$, which can then be simplified to $\frac{977}{425}$.

$y$ then is solved for by plugging $x$ back into the equation.

EDIT: Someone posted this solution before me, but I'll leave it because their math is a little off.

Comment: :D I fixed my math lol.  Btw, you can edit other people's posts, which comes in handy for relatively small errors.

Comment: Oh, okay, didn't know that.